# VS Code integrated terminal UTF-8 input problem

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, visual-c++, utf-8

I don't understand why my question was closed? The problem is not in the encoding. The problem is in the integrated terminal of vs code.

I am working with MSVC compiler in VS Code. I set the integrated terminal to powershell 7. The code page is UTF-8, that is 65001. There is no problem with functions like printf and puts, UTF-8 characters can be printed to the screen, but when I try to read utf-8 to a buffer with fgets and print the buffer to the screen, I cannot get the desired result. Here is the code:

```
#include <locale.h> 
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
char *charset = setlocale(LC_ALL, ".UTF-8"); 
char buffer[64]; puts("Enter something..."); 
fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin); 
printf("charset: %s\ninput: %s\n", charset, buffer); }
```

Here is the output:

```
Enter something...
ĞÜŞİÖÇ
charset: Turkish_Turkey.utf8
input:
```

When I run the same program with Powershell 7 it works fine. But it doesn't work properly in integrated terminal of vs code.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: What does `fgets()` return? Question is, whether this is a problem with the output or input.

Comment: how are you checking the code page? running `chcp.com` in the _exact same_ console where you are running the program?

Comment: @drum, the output I was expecting was 'ĞÜŞİÖÇ'

Comment: @starball I made the code page UTF-8 in windows settings. I checked it with chcp command.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Same with buffer